# Issues with TFS on Visual Studio 2019 Community: Uploading files to TFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, visual-studio-2019, tfs-2015

In visual studio 2019 Community I have an ASP.NET MVC project on which I have done some upgrades and downgrades of bootstrap nuget package in order to test some functionalities. Finally I have installed bootstrap 3.4.1 because it seems it is the version is working ok in my case.

Now, in team explorer, the pending changes are shown as below:

[image]

I do not know why there are some files, those beginning with bootstrap-theme* that are marked to be deleted.

In the solution explorer those files are appearing like below:

[image]

Files bootstrap-theme* are not marked with a red thick, it seems like they are not uploaded in the server, but they are.

Below the files on the source control version window, they are marked to be deleted:

[image]

What I want is to overwrite the files on the TFS server with the ones in my local. I want to upload these files to TFS. How can I do it?

Comment: Hi @Ralph, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please have a try with it. any update, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retain the files that are marked as deleted?

If you do not want to retain these files, you can try to pull the source files from your TFS server and manually delete these files from the project folder, then push the updates to your TFS server to see if it can work.

What type of version control are you using? Git or TFVC? You can try using the related commands to check out and check in the updates to see if the same issue occurs.